# Use AWS Secret Manager With Minikube Local Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, minikube, aws-secrets-manager

I have a local Kubernetes cluster running on my mac using minikube.
I want to mount secrets stored on AWS Secret Manager into my pod.

Basically I'm trying to achieve what's described in [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-aws-secrets-configuration-provider-with-kubernetes-secrets-store-csi-driver/) tutorial, but for a cluster running locally, and not on EKS.

I've installed the CSI driver by running

```
helm repo add secrets-store-csi-driver https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver/charts
```

and

```
helm install -n kube-system csi-secrets-store secrets-store-csi-driver/secrets-store-csi-driver
```

and also installed the aws provider service account by applying:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-aws/main/deployment/aws-provider-installer.yaml
```

In addition I've applied my 'secretProviderClass' yml to my minikube cluster:

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: mypod-aws-secrets
  namespace: default
spec:
  provider: aws
  parameters:
    objects: |
        - objectName: "testSecret"
          objectType: "secretsmanager"
          jmesPath:
            - path: testSecretKey
              objectAlias: testSecretKey
```

and lastly in my pod's deployment.yml I tried to mount using this `mypod-aws-secrets` (just the relevant part):

```
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            component: myPod
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                component: myPod
        spec:
            serviceAccountName: application-pod-sa
            volumes:
            - name: secrets-store-inline
              csi:
                driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
                readOnly: true
                volumeAttributes:
                    secretProviderClass: mypod-aws-secrets
```

However, the pod failed to start and I get the following error:

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "secrets-store-inline" : rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to mount secrets store objects for pod default/myPod-579bdf9b57-dd9tq, err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to retrieve region from node. error Region not found
```

Which make sense to me because so far, I didn't let my minikube cluster know any info about the concrete AWS Secret Manager, nor did I gave my minikube cluster any permission to access this AWS Secret Manager on my AWS account.
My questions are:

1. Where/how should I add this information?
2. What's missing in order to get it to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The CSI driver for AWS Secrets and Configuration Manager [documentation](https://github.com/aws/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-aws/tree/main#requirements) says this is only for AWS EKS clusters.

So there are a few things that are missing in `minikube` (and any other k8s distribution):

- The region, i.e the error you're facing. This is actually taken from the k8s node label `topology.kubernetes.io/region` that is added by most cloud k8s providers. You can add it on your `minikube` node but it won't get you much further... see below
- Credentials for `secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-aws` to open a session with AWS and provide access respecting the IAM role annotated on the serviceAccount.

For this later point, I haven't researched further but I suspect that this is thanks to EKS providing IRSA (IAM Roles for ServiceAccounts) abilities by default. I don't know if it's possible to get the same functionality outside of AWS or even EKS.

Maybe digging into "IAM Anywhere" could provide a solution, but at a quick glance it seems like a lot of setup and that doesn't match the typical "temporary local k8s" usage of `minikube`.

Another thing to progress might be to dig into `secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-aws` code and see if it's possible to provide it with AWS credentials (an access key / token?) so it's able to open that session.